# error: invalid arch-independent ELF magic

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I had a Ubuntu guest OS(18.04) running on Windows 7. I upgraded my host OS to Windows 10. After installing the same Virtual Box software my Ubuntu OS didn't boot.

it shows:
error: invalid arch-independent ELF magic.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>

Comment: Check the settings of that VM in General > Basic > Version, change it to x86 or x64 as your guest.

Comment: It is 64  bit which I have installed.